# "Anticipate" for "look forward to"

Tags: word-usage

Can "anticipate" be safely used as a substitute for "look forward to" in informal prose like emails and general correspondence, but also in business writing?

e.g.

*I'm **anticipating** to hear from you.*
http://419.bittenus.com/12/9/gracejohnson.html

*I **anticipate** hearing from you.*
http://www.siue.edu/~tmarsha/

Comment: If it's truly informal or "not so formal," couldn't you use whatever you'd like?

Comment: *I'm anticipating to hear ...* is not acceptable. *Anticipate* cannot take an infinitive as an object.

Comment: @bin Yes, it can. In AE at least...

Comment: have you considered that some colloquial forms of AmEng and BrEng are preferable to others? That some are best left to speech while others should not be used in formal writing? It seems to me that you have already made your mind up before asking any of these questions. In 21 questions I have yet to see one accepted answer from you. Don't be dismayed if people stop answering them. You barely thank them for even taking the trouble in any case! And you should learn how to embed your links, the links detract attention from the content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would avoid it in informal writing in most cases. There are a few senses under which it could be understood as applying to "…hear from you", but most don't match very well.

I would avoid it even more carefully in formal writing, since in formal writing it is best to avoid any uses that are commonly considered incorrect.

Generally I would only *anticipate* that which I took action to prepare for, or that which I took action to prevent. E.g. I anticipate welcome visits by making sure I have food and drink to serve, and anticipate unwelcome visits by having a compound bow and some arrows under my bed, along with various other weapons around my house. I don't anticipate responses to correspondence, because there is nothing to do but wait for them to come.

Comment: How about if I say "I'm anticipating your prompt response or reply", can a phrasing like that work for business emails?

Comment: It's disputed; some people would say it's fine and some would say it's incorrect unless you are doing something about the expected response. Generally my descriptivist tendencies would lead me to say it's correct, but in formal writing it's perhaps best to avoid what is disputed (to not just be correct, but to be seen to be correct). For that reason, while I'd defend your choice to use it if you chose, I still would advise against it if you asked.

Comment: What if the people I'm writing to are American, is that sense of "anticipate" kind of more acceptable to their ears?

Answer (score 1):

"Anticipate" feels a bit formal to me.  "Await" or "eagerly waiting" might be a bit more informal.

Grammatically, yes, it is legal, and it's just a touch on the formal side, but I would probably still put it in an email to my grandma.

Comment: Which of the following intensifiers work best with "anticipate"? Eagerly, anxiously, very much, antsily ;)?

Comment: With anticipate?  Usually, it doesn't need intensification (eagerly anticipate is a bit redundant), but it can be used with nervously or anxiously if you want to more finely express the emotion at hand.  "Eagerly await" is in common use.  [NGrams result](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=anticipate%2Ceagerly+anticipate%2C+await%2C+eagerly+await&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Canticipate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceagerly%20anticipate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cawait%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceagerly%20await%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: How about if I say "I can hardly wait for (or on) your reply or response, does that do the trick just as well?

Comment: That works fine.  "I can hardly wait for your reply.  Write back soon!"

Comment: How about if I say "I just can't wait and hear from you guys" or "I can hardly wait to hear from you guys", or "I can hardly wait on (or for) you guys' reply", does that work just as fine...for casual emails and business writing at least ;)?

Comment: "I can hardly wait to hear from you guys" or "I just can't wait **to** hear from you guys" are all fine.

Comment: Can't "wait" be followed by "and" just like "try", "go", "come", "be sure", and "take care", and so saying "I can hardly wait and see you" sounds in colloquial contexts like an acceptable alternative to "I can hardly wait to see you" ;) ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a native speaker, but I usually use *anticipate* to convey an expectation, or a prediction... or both, as in "I expect [this] to happen".

I'd consider *foresee* and the aformentioned *expect* as alternatives.

*Look forward to* on the other hand sounds "warmer" to me, as in "I can't wait for you to do this".