# Anticipation with a positive tone

Tags: expressions

I am looking for a word or phrase that **means** *I am happy that something will be happening*. Existing phrases along this line already exist in popular writing:

> Movie Y is the *most anticipated* since Movie X.
>   I am really *looking forward to* Christmas this year

*Look forward to* and *anticipate* are synonyms  but nether spells out the mood in which one looks forward to something. Really, what does "most anticipated" actually mean? A load of people expect that a movie will be made? Great, but it doesn't mean they want to watch it.

I respect that these phrases have built up a convention for meaning positive things,
I'd just like something more explicit.

**Edit:** I did notice this [question hit the wall](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/151409/anticipate-for-look-forward-to) before posting. I'd like to think I've been more objective but point out issues and I'll try to fix.

Comment: I am excited that Movie Y is coming out soon.  I am getting excited because Christmas is getting close.

Comment: *To look forward to* **does** usually signify eager anticipation: "I'm looking forward to my birthday!"

Comment: An ELU magic moment. Three great answers and no fluff or discussion :)

Answer (score 4):

The first word that comes to mind for me as a native American English speaker is "eager."  Oxford dictionaries defines eager as follows:

> [Eager](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/eager) - adjective - (Of a person) wanting to do or have something very much
>
> *the man was eager to please*
>
> *young intellectuals eager for knowledge*

In the example you provided I might say, "I am eager for the release of Movie X."

A few other (informal) possibilities I might use colloquially are: "jazzed," "thrilled," "itching," or "dying."

*I am jazzed for the release of Videogame X next month.*

*I am thrilled about Christmas this year.*

*I am itching for my wife to get home from work.*

*I am dying to get out of this office and go fishing.*

But the most common choice I would make to express anticipation for something is "looking forward to."

*I am looking forward to a cold beer when I get home.*

Answer (score 3):

Also consider *[pumped up](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pumped_up#Adjective)* (“Excited, particularly due to anticipation” – wiktionary) (or just *pumped*, without a preposition) and   *[stoked](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stoked)* (“(slang) Feeling excitement or an exciting rush” – wiktionary), both of which are used to express excitement about near-future events.

Unfortunately, *pumped* seems a bit clumsy when used in the examples in the question, which concern movies and Christmas.  But  *stoked* probably works ok informally:

> I am so stoked about this new movie *When the Rains Come*!
>   I am so stoked about Christmas this year!

Answer (score 3):

Extreme emotion can be indicated using the container (or failure of container?) metaphor:

> I can hardly contain myself waiting for the third 'Hobbit Movie'.

While 'cannot etc contain oneself' is normally restricted to the emotion of excitement, in

> He was beside himself waiting for the party to start.

there needs to be a direct (beside himself with joy) or deducible (as here) contextual indicator of the type of extreme emotion involved. Anger and anxiety are quite possible.

'He was out of his mind with ...' is usually reserved for negative emotions.

Answer (score 0):

I was also searching for same word.

I think the best word that suits is "Anticipation", which means expecting something to happen(in a good way), and someone can say predicting as well but I find it as a partial answer.
If one predicts the future that can be intentional, and it can be either good or bad.

These are the words which might be the one we are looking for(or do correct me if I'm wrong)

1. Unintentional, bad feeling about future : Premunition, Presauge, Presentiment
2. Unintentional, good feeling about future: Anticipation, Auspicate
3. Intentional, Bad feeling                : Augur
4. Intentional, good feeling               : Eager,
5. Neutral - could be good or bad          : Predict, Betoken, Foretoken, Foretell, Forecast, bespeak